# Retrieve Data in dynamic tabs

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

here i'm trying to click on any tabs to retrieve it's own data i did it well and it really retrieves the data of one raw only ?! any help?

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="tabs-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          @foreach($departments as $department)
          <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-{{ $department->id }}" aria-expanded="false">{{ $department->name }}</a></li>
          @endforeach


        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          @foreach($works as $work)
          <div id="tab-{{ $work->department_id }}" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row employees">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="image view view-first"> <img class="img-responsive" src="" name="imaged" alt="image"> </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h4>{{ $work->address }}  </h4>
                      <p>{{ $work->body }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit-portfolio.html"> تعديل</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger demo4"> حذف
                  </button>
                </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--  -->
  </div>
```

i don't need to make it ajax if anyone have a good reason for why it give me only one record for each department?

Comment: what do you mean by it gives you only one raw ?

Comment: i mean that i have 5 values say 2 of them having department_id=1 
it only give me one record of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get one record for department is that your loop create one tab panel per work, for example if you have 2 works (1,2) belongs to one department (1) the result would be 2 tabs with the same id set to 1:

departments:

```
id     
-----
1
```

works:

```
id      department_id
---------------------
1       1
2       1
```

Html result:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
    ...
</div>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
    ...
</div>
```

note that both tabs have the same id `tab-1`.

**Solution**

group works by department_id, something like this:

```
 $works = Work::all()->groupBy('department_id');
```

and then in your view:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    @foreach($works as $department_id => $department_works)
        <div id="tab-{{ $department_id }}" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row employees">
                    @foreach($department_works as $work)
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div class="image view view-first"> <img class="img-responsive" src="" name="imaged" alt="image"> </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>{{ $work->address }}  </h4>
                                <p>{{ $work->body }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit-portfolio.html"> تعديل</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger demo4"> حذف </button>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Hope this helps